# How do I make the line always go through the points?

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I'm drawing a graph with achartengine. I'm still working on the display, but one thing that's caught my eye already is that the graph lines don't go through the points, they take some path that roughly traces their shape:

[image]

How can I make my lines always go through my points?

Comment: Are you creating a line of best fit here, or are you actually plotting a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong places (Renderers) for a solution, in the end I noticed I was using a `ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView`, changed to `ChartFactory.getLineChartView` and all is good.

Comment: i am facing the same issue , i want to display smooth curves so it need to use ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView,  it working with ChartFactory.getLineChartView but i don't need straight lines